# Predicate's test method implementation

Tags: lambda, java-8, predicate

In the Java SE 8 Programmer I Study guide, they have a method like:

```
public class PredicateSearch {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
        animals.add( new Animal("fish", false, true ));

        print( animals, a -> a.canSwim() );
    }

    private static void print( List<Animal> animals, Predicate<Animal> checker ) {
        for( Animal animal : animals ) {
            if ( checker.test( animal ))
                System.out.print( animal + " " );
        }
    }
}
```

It was stated that the gist of predicate is something like

```
public interface Predicate<T> { boolean test(T t);
}
```

I wonder when and how this `test` method implemented.. I am still quite confused with lambda and predicate

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Answer (score 0):

your print statement will look like in previous java versions

```
print( animals, new Predicate<Animal>(){

        @Override
        public boolean test(Animal t) {
            return t.canSwim();
        }

    } );
```